# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.android

So I tried almost all the answers that I found in stackoverflow but none worked.
I get that error every time I try to `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);`

> Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1 in com.abcbraga.abcfichaobras:layout/activitymain: Binary XML file line #1 in com.abcbraga.abcfichaobras:layout/activitymain: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView'

activity_main.xml looks something like this:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but even here I get an error on the designer
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOUn4.png)

I also tried to remove headerLayout and menu but didnt result

HeaderLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="Image"
        android:id="@+id/header_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

SetContentView

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar")]
  public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
  {
    public FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig;
    public FloatingActionButton fab;
    public FirebaseFirestore db;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
      Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
      SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

      fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
      fab.Click += FabOnClick;
      //Init Firestore
      db = GetDataBase();

      firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.Instance;
      FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().Build();
      firebaseRemoteConfig.SetConfigSettings(configSettings);
      DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
      ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
      drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
      toggle.SyncState();
      NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
      navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the context where you're calling `SetContentView(...)` ?

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: I run with your codes,but it couldn't reproduce the issue,it works well.Could you show your `app_bar_main` xml ?

Comment: `app:itemTextColor="#79847A"` I presume that the text didn't had color so it wasn't be able to show it and it crashed.